# docker リンクエラー: Cannot link to a non running container: /mariadb AS /wordpress/mysql

Tags: mysql, centos, docker, wordpress, mariadb

wordpressとmariadbのdockerを使って、centos7でwordpressウェブサーバーを構築したいと思います。
以下のコマンドを実行すると、

```
docker pull wordpress
docker pull mariadb
docker run --name mariadb -e MY_ROOT_PASSWORD=AceTaffy -d mariadb
docker run --name wordpress --link mariadb:mysql -p 80:80 wordpress
```

エラーが出ました：
`/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /mariadb AS /wordpress/mysql.` 
コマンドはlinuxの入門書「ゼロからはじめるLinuxサーバー構築・運用ガイド 動かしながら学ぶWebサーバーの作り方」通りに実行してるのに、うまく出来ませんでした。
リンクが失敗する理由を教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

表示されているエラーは、接続先 (ここでは MariaDB) が起動していない状態でリンクしようとしている場合に出るようです。

`docker run` を続けて実行しているようであれば、まず MariaDB のコンテナが正常に起動したのを確認してから Wordpress のコンテナを起動してみてください。